# How to insert a g:text object inside another html element?

Tags: sidebar, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm developing a Windows gadget. There is a function called addTextObject on the background object which creates the object I want which I can later add glowing and shadows to it. But the problem is that I am not able to control the objects location. For example, if I want to append it inside a div or span or td, the appendChild method is not working.  How can I fix this?

```
var txtGlow = document.getElementById('imgBackground').addTextObject("test", "Verdana", 25, "Red", 50, 50);
            txtGlow.opacity = 100;
            txtGlow.addGlow("yellow", 50, 50);
            var theDiv = document.getElementById('divx');
            txtGlow.value = theDiv.innerText;
            theDiv.appendChild(txtGlow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text and image objects added to the background aren't elements and as such can't be appended to just any element.  You can create a `<g:text>` element in your HTML markup, but they don't behave [in the same way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676240(VS.85).aspx#_sidebar_basic_presentation_elements):

> **Note** This method does not expose the objects as g:image or g:text elements. You can locate and assign the objects using the document.getElementById("...") method, but the g:image or g:text methods and properties are not available.

You could create the element using *document.createElement()* or *innerHTML*.